# How to replace the Firefox Portable splash screen?

Tags: firefox, portability

I'm customizing the Firefox Portable edition, downloaded from Portable Apps, and as a part of the process I want to replace the splash screen. I already replaced the image file named FirefoxPortable.jpg inside the FirefoxPortable > Other > Source folder. Also, I edited the FirefoxPortable.ini not to show the splash screen (for test purposes) and copied that same splash screen image file named as splash.jpg to another folders too. The result: it keeps showing the original PortableApps' splash screen.

Does anybody know how to get rid of it or just to replace it? I think that image file might be cached somewhere.

If anybody found this problem before, I'd be glad to hear how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move the ini file to the root of the application directory.

FirefoxPortable.ini should be in the same directory as the FirefoxPortable.exe and the data, app, and Other folders.

this is specified the the ini file

```
# The above options are explained in the included readme.txt
# This INI file is an example only and is not used unless it is placed as described in the included readme.txt
```

as well as the readme.txt file

```
FIREFOXPORTABLE.INI CONFIGURATION
=================================
The Firefox Portable Launcher will look for an ini file called 
FirefoxPortable.ini
within its directory.  If you are happy with the default options, it is not necessary,
though.  There is an example INI included with this package to get you started within
the Other\Source directory.  Note that it will not work from this location as it must
be placed in the same directory as FirefoxPortable.exe.
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked to hide/show the splash screen. Now I want to replace it. Do you know how? Do I need to move the image file to the root as well?

Comment: to actually change the splash screen image you will need to recompile the app with the new splash image.

see here:
https://portableapps.com/node/14746